# rsync without remote having it

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, rsync

I'm wondering whether there's a possiblity of using `rsync` when the remote server doesn't have it installed (or at least not available to my user).

The remote server is a shared host, and while I have ssh shell access to it, what is available to me on that shell is **extremely** basic (one of the reasons I'm going to switch hosts soon, but that's out of the question now).

Is there any precompiled rsync binary (I believe the host is a x64 Red Hat, but I'm not sure) I could download to my host (using wget or ftp) to use it? I can't use gcc on it or anything to build from source on the remote host. I have full access to my local linux box (ubuntu), <strike>would just copying the rsync binary to the remote host work?</strike> (**edit**: seems it doesn't, I tested it and it requires a specific version of `libc.so.6`. I actually copied the required libraries from my ubuntu and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` just to test, and it gives a segmentation fault, which I can't debug further since I have no tools on that shell)

Otherwise, any recommendations to do incremental syncs? I can do [s]ftp to that remote host, but not much more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up compiling a static version on my local ubuntu box and uploaded it to the remote host (then used `--rsync-path` to set the path to my statically linked binary).

I didn't have high hopes for it to work, because even the linker tells you that you need to have the same glibc version even for statically linked binaries... but it did work, and it's "rsyncing" right now.

Answer (score 3):

[rsync-static](https://github.com/JBBgameich/rsync-static/) is a GitHub project which provides precompiled `rsync` [releases for 3 architectures](https://github.com/JBBgameich/rsync-static/releases):

- x86
- ARM
- AArch64

Comment: are there precompiled binaries for MIPS anywhere?

Comment: Son of a gun, worked like a charm

Comment: Shame the x86 does not run on WIndows 10 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an `sshfs` to the remote server and then point `rsync` at it.

```
sshfs server:/ ~/mnt/server
rsync -options path/to/source ~/mnt/server/path/to/sync/to
```

You may need to tweak `sshfs` and/or `rsync` options so it doesn't get confused by permissions/ownership appearing different on the remote side.